# Win32 C++ detect USB-drive corruption

Tags: c++, winapi, usb, corruption

I am working on a kiosk application using Windows 7 as the OS, and Win32 C++ to detect and manage USB drives.  We just found a bug where, if a USB is corrupt in some way, the OS will pop up the following dialog which is hidden behind the kiosk application and therefore never gets shown.

[image: image of the dialog]

When a user goes to copy to this drive, the application crashes.

I have been looking for a way to detect when I get a USB DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL notification whether or not this newly added USB is corrupt, but haven't come up with any good possibilities.  What I have come up with is the possibility of calling DeviceIoControl() and passing IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO as the control code, since the PARTITION_INFORMATION structure returned can tell me whether the partition type is recognized or not.  But this doesn't necessarily tell me whether the USB is corrupt.  I assume this is more likely to tell whether this is a recognized NTFS format, as opposed to a format written by a Linux or Mac system.

Can anyone tell me how I could go about detecting corruption in a newly added USB drive, so that I can take the necessary next steps?

One more thing.  I've tried to purposefully create a corruption on my USB drive so that I can emulate the issue found by our user, but Win7 seems to be smart enough to stop me from doing that.  Does anyone know of a way to create a corrupted USB drive for test purposes?

Comment: Hmm, don't try to solve a big problem when you only have a small one.  Copying a file to a disk drive should never crash your app.  Lots more reasons why it would fail that don't have anything to do with a corrupted flash drive.  Start by testing copying to a full drive, that's easy.

Comment: In addition to fixing your crashing bug as suggested by Hans Passant, you may want to disable the popup from appearing: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/227778-scan-fix-removable-disk-prompt-disable-windows.html I haven't tried it, but an easy way to create a USB drive that would cause Windows to display this dialogue would be to physically remove a FAT32 formatted drive while in the middle of copying a large file to it.

Comment: Sorry about the delay in getting back. Pulled off on something else.  I understand that there is an issue with my app crashing at all.  That needs to be fixed, but I'm in search of a way to create the situation again so I can see exactly what was going on at the time of the crash.  Codegaurd gave an answer below that seems to give me what I need.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: Continuing to look into this at the moment.  Will post what I find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're incorrectly relating this to USB. Instead, it's a volume flag. Obtaining this status is possible via WMI, for example. See `Win32_LogicalDisk.VolumeDirty` - if TRUE, then disk requires chkdsk. Once you know the volume requires repairing, you can run chkdsk.exe from your program.

You can also use `fsutil dirty query f:` to check if volume requires repair, and `fsutil dirty set f:` to manually set this bit. That also allows you to make a test USB.

On some computers, Scan&Fix popup may be disabled. Still, if you set dirty bit, Scan&Fix will show computers where it's not disabled.

PS: I think you should figure why your app crashes and fix that as well. I believe that is a separate problem in your app.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I am especially thankful for the info on creating a test USB.  Now I can start to figure out where the problem lies in my code.  Agreed about fixing the app crash.  Since this bug was reported to me by a remote customer and I didn't have access to their USB for testing, my first need was to get a USB that I can test with in order to make sure the fix is appropriate.  Now I can fix the crash, and also test ahead of time to prompt a user to run chkdsk or cancel. Thanks again.

Comment: Posted this incorrectly above.  I'm continuing to look into this at the moment. Will post what I find.

Comment: Ok, so I thought I didn't make a corrupted USB drive, but after using "fsutil dirty query f:", I get back "Volume - f: is Dirty".  But when I ejected it, removed it and then reinserted it, I didn't get the dialog shown above.  This seems to mean that a dirty fs is not what is causing the dialog to query for scan/fix.

Comment: Just to check it out, using that command on another USB that I haven't messed around with produces "Volume - g: is NOT Dirty".

Comment: I just tested it myself; an usb flash produced the scan&fix message both on Win7 and Win8 after `fsutil dirty set`. Can it be that your flash drive is not NTFS formatted, or you didn't put the correct drive letter in place of `f:` ?

Comment: Ah, yes I tried fsutil dirty set f: but it's not an NTFS formatted drive.  It's FAT32, as it would seem most USBs are, from my looking at the others that I have.

Comment: But I am getting that the drive is dirty.  I just ran chkdsk /r f: to clean it and it came up clean again.  I then deleted some of the files and tried overfilling again and it wasn't dirty, even though the final write failed.  Then I deleted and tried copying a huge file and pulled the USB during the copy, and now it's dirty again. Cleaned again and then wrote another file and let it copy to completion, then pulled the USB without ejecting, and when I inserted it again and ran the command it showed up not dirty.  So for me dirty seems to mean that a file write was ended incorrectly.

Comment: But the more interesting thing is that when it's considered dirty the scan/fix dialog doesn't show.  Could there be a difference between how fsutil is checking for dirty for a file that was not closed properly vs actually having the dirty bit checked?  I mean, could it be reporting dirty and the dirty bit isn't actually set?  Still working on getting Win32_LogicalDisk.VolumeDirty going.

Comment: Just try formatting as NTFS. As for `Win32_LogicalDisk.VolumeDirty`, you can use `wbemtest.exe` to `Connect` and then `Query...` for `SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE VolumeDirty=TRUE`

Comment: Can it be that you have already disabled popup from appearing, as suggested by Ross Ridge?

Comment: Ok, so I formatted to NTFS and ran "fsutil dirty set f:".  It came back saying f: now marked dirty.  I downloaded WMI and installed, and then ran wbemtext.exe, connected, and ran the query.  I got back DeviceID="F:".  So wbemtext.exe and fsutil dirty query both agree on that point.  But now that it's dirty, I eject it and then pull and reinsert it, and I didn't get that dialog.  Very strange, since you said you did.  Btw, I'm running on Win7.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79031/discussion-between-codeguard-and-bmahf).